# Flutter Framework is already pre-compiled?

Tags: java, flutter, dart, frameworks, libraries

Pre-Made Libraries are provided by the SDK, Like Java JDK, Android SDK, Dart SDK. All these Libraries that we use in our code are already pre-compiled or it gets compile with our code?